# Using WCF with on-premise ServiceBus

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, servicebus

I'm looking to build a bidirectional communication service using ServiceBus 1.1 for Windows Server, there's a receive queue and a send queue, classic setup.

Now the thing is that I'd like to have a WCF service communicating over these queues.

Tom Hollander writes about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2011/10/07/using-service-bus-queues-with-wcf.aspx but the trouble is that the binding expects the address to end in "servicebus.windows.net" and is quite upset if that's not the case:

> The Uri provided sb does not match Service Bus domain:
>   servicebus.windows.net.

What is going on and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piyushjo/archive/2011/09/27/azure-service-bus-working-with-the-appfabriclabs-account.aspx) deals with the issue. You need to set your ServiceBus hostnames in configuration.

Comment: the only issue with that blog post is that it says that the name of the file should be ServiceBus.xml instead of .config.